# New AVD not creating properly in android

Tags: android

I have copied `android-sdk-linux` folder from one PC to another PC, and installed Eclipse and  Set appropriate paths (both tools and  Platform-tools) but I cannot create any avd.

When I try to create new avd from Android Virtual Device Manager, it only show this error message in console when I click new avd.

```
[2012-05-29 23:29:27 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2012-05-29 23:29:27 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

I put my android-sdk-linux folder in `/home/dharma/Android-sdk-linux`

On my pc, I didn't find `home/username/.Android/avd`. So what can I do to run my app in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK does have some requirements on the Ubuntu 64-bit base:

## adb

sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386

## aapt

sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878445/ubuntu-error-failed-to-create-the-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reinstall the API version as well.  Simply run `android` from command line and make sure the API level you are using is listed as installed.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and this is what I've found.

If you're on 64-bit, you may not be having the `ia32-libs` package installed.
try installing the package and see if that works.

If it doesn't, try giving the files in the `Tools` directory in the Android SDK folder, execute permissions (Given that they don't have these permissions already)